# Can't select File's Owner in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have created a small IOS app using the Single View application template, without storyboard support (I'm running Xcode 4.2.1). After the shell was created, I proceeded to put a single text field in the ViewController XIB file. However, I can't hook up the "Did End On Exit" event to the File's Owner. Only First Responder is available to hook up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`UITextField` doesn't generate an event.  Can you add a button and connect to `File's Owner`?

If you want to act on `UITextField` events you should set it's delegate to `File's Owner` (or something else), and implement particular `UITextFieldDelegate` methods that you are interested in.

Comment: The delegate declaration did it! Thanks a lot!